# How to upload multiple images in node js using the formidable module

Tags: node.js, express, formidable, multiple-file-upload

Am working on a project that deals with file upload, have been able to upload single image in my database, but now i want to upload multiple images using the formidable node js module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable?

If so, in their README they have the following config:

```
form.multiples = false;

If this option is enabled, when you call form.parse, the files argument will contain arrays of files for inputs which submit multiple files using the HTML5 multiple attribute.
```

The `req.files` will then be an array of files/images.